# Como formatar uma data exibindo o nome do mês em angular?

Tags: angularjs

Tenho um objeto `Date` no meu controller em Angular.

```
 $scope.date = new Date;
```

Eu gostaria de formatar essa data, na view, para aparecer o nome do mês por extenso. Quero que o nome seja exibido em português.

Existe alguma formatação para exibir isso em angular?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use o filtro [date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

Passando **`MMM`** como parâmetro, a saída será o nome do mês encurtado (Jan - Dez). Usando **`MMMM`** a saída será o nome do mês por extenso (Janeiro - Dezembro).

Também é possível usar o filtro `date` direto no controller, injetando `$filter`.

Para que os nomes sejam mostrados em português, você precisará ter o *script* de internacionalização referenciado no projeto.

Exemplo completo:

```js
var app = angular.module('dt-app', []);

app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $filter){
  $scope.data = new Date();  
  $scope.dataFormatada = $filter('date')($scope.data, 'MMMM');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.6.4/angular-locale_pt-br.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="dt-app">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div>    
      <h4>Formatando direto na view</h4>
      {{ data | date: 'MMM'}}<br>
      {{ data | date: 'MMMM'}}
    </div>
    
    <hr>
    
    <div id="dt-ctrl">
      <h4>Formatando no controller:</h4>
      {{ dataFormatada }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Caso deseje utilizar puramente `Javascript`:

```js
function formatarDataExtenso(data) {
  // Meses possíveis
  var meses = ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'];
  // Dias possíveis
  var diasSemana = ['Domingo', 'Segunda-feira', 'Terça-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sábado'];
  // Partes da data informada
  var dia = data.getDate();
  var dias = data.getDay();
  var mes = data.getMonth();
  var ano = data.getYear();
  // Resultado
  var extenso = '';

  // Para o navegador Netscape o ano começa em 1900
  if (navigator.appName == "Netscape") {
    ano = ano + 1900;
  }

  return extenso = diasSemana[dias] + ', ' + dia + ' de ' + meses[mes] + ' de ' + ano;
}

// Teste com a data atual
console.log(formatarDataExtenso(new Date()));
```